# Unable to debug Go code on Windows using VSCode/GoLand (Getting '%1 is not a valid Win32 application')

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, goland, delve, confluent-kafka-go

When I am trying to debug this Go application using VS Code and dlv, I get the following error:

> Failed to launch: could not launch process: fork/exec
> C:\Users\MyUser\Workspaces\goworkspace\github.com...__debug_bin.exe:%1
> is not a valid Win32 application.

**But when I comment out the kafka code (please refer main.go) and then try to debug, the debugger works and the breakpoint is hit.**

Things that I already tried:

- Running the application in other machine, which worked!
- Reinstalling Go on Windows.
- Moving the application to a different directory.
- Reinstalling and updating VSCode and the related Golang extension/tools.
- Checked the environment variables but did not find anything suspicious.
- Blocked the Windows Defender, but that did not work either.
- Running the 'Windows Memory Diagnostics' tool.
- Reinstalling tdm-gcc (used by kafka)
- Using Jetbrains Goland, but getting a similar error

> could not launch process: fork/exec C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\GoLand___go_build_main_go.exe: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

- Using the 'dlv debug' command from Windows terminal, get similar error again

> could not launch process: fork/exec C:\Users\MyUser\Workspaces\goworkspace\github.com\org\app-name\cmd__debug_bin: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Version Details :

- Windows 10 Pro 20H2
- GoLand 2021.2.3
- go version go1.17.1 windows/amd64
- Delve Debugger Delve Debugger
- VS Code Version 1.60.2

Please refer the code below,

**main.go**

```
func main() {
log.Println("Starting api server")

cfg, err := config.LoadConfig()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("LoadConfig: %v", err)
}

//Kakfa Code Begin
c, err := kafka.NewKafkaConsumer(cfg)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Kafka Consumer Creation: %v", err)
}
kafka.ListenToTopics(cfg, c, []string{"topic-name"})
//Kafka Code End
```

}

**kakfa.go**

```
package kafka

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/my-user/config"
    "gopkg.in/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go.v1/kafka"
)

func NewKafkaConsumer(cfg *config.Config) (*kafka.Consumer, error) {

    config := cfg.Kafka

    return kafka.NewConsumer(&kafka.ConfigMap{
        "bootstrap.servers": config.BootstrapServers,
        "security.protocol": config.SecurityProtocol,
        "sasl.mechanisms":   config.SASLMechanisms,
        "sasl.username":     config.SASLUsername,
        "sasl.password":     config.SASLPassword,
        "group.id":          config.GroupID,
        "auto.offset.reset": config.AutoOffsetReset,
    })
}

func ListenToTopics(cfg *config.Config, c *kafka.Consumer, topics []string) {
    c.SubscribeTopics(topics, nil)

    for {
        msg, err := c.ReadMessage(-1)
        defer c.Close()
        if err == nil {
            schemaID := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(msg.Value[1:5])
            schema, err := getLatestAVROSchemaById(cfg, int(schemaID))
            if err != nil {
                panic(fmt.Sprintf("Error getting the schema with id '%d' %s", schemaID, err))
            }
            native, _, _ := schema.Codec.NativeFromBinary(msg.Value[5:])
            value, _ := schema.Codec.TextualFromNative(nil, native)
            fmt.Printf("Here is the message %s\n", string(value))
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Error consuming the message: %v (%v)\n", err, msg)
        }
    }
}
```

**go env**

```
set GO111MODULE=
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\MyUser\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\MyUser\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.17.1
set GCCGO=gccgo
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=NUL
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build3863829792=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Please let me know if I should post this question to some specific forum/community.

Comment: Are you on Windows with x86 or x64 architecture?

Comment: @s0xzwasd I am on Windows x64

Comment: What is your `go env` output?

Comment: @s0xzwasd Updated my question with go env output. Please check the question.

Comment: What `wmic OS get OSArchitecture` in the terminal returns?

Comment: @s0xzwasd 
OSArchitecture
64-bit

Comment: I have two envs, where setup is exactly the same (gcc, vscode, go, dlv) however one has similar issue as you do and I am banging my head against wall to understand why. Currently I have tracked it down that this seems to be related how delve builds your solution before debugging when using CGO. If you do `go build -gcflags="all=-N -l"`  the solution works fine (gcc/cgo is ok). And then as a workaround you can do `("mode": "exec", "program": "program.exe")` in the launch.json. However its not clear to me yet what is causing the dlv to behave like this when building for debugging from vscode.